# How to combine all non numbers into a list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have the base case

```
variable_part(X) :- var(X), !.
variable_part(X) :- number(X).
variable_part(X+Y) :- variable_part(X), variable_part(Y).
variable_part(X-Y) :- variable_part(X), variable_part(Y).
```

I am trying to make it so that all the elements of the list should have the form Atom*Number and to have it sorted but im not really sure where to start.

Comment: Would you like also "so for example variable_part(5-(3+x),N) should succeed with N=2" ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need an additional argument that holds the list of variables. In the variable base case you collect the variable, in the number base case you don't:

```
variable_part(X,[X]) :- var(X).
variable_part(X,[]) :- number(X).
```

For the recursion you need to combine the variable lists:

```
variable_part(Op,Vars) :-
    nonvar(Op),
    Op = X + Y,
    variable_part(X,V1),
    variable_part(Y,V2),
    append(V1,V2,Vars).
```

I have also removed the cut from the base case and replaced it with an explicit nonvar check followed by unification for the recursive cases. As a next step you could replace the append by a predicate that combines the variables onto your multiplication representation (alternatively you do this as a postprocessing step). You might make your life easier by choosing atoms to represent the variables of your equation system though (see also this [discussion](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/data) of a clean vs. defaulty representation).

```
variable_part(v(X),[(X,1)]).
variable_part(X,[]) :- number(X).
variable_part(X+Y,Vars) :-
    variable_part(X,V1),
    variable_part(Y,V2),
    append(V1,V2,Vars).
variable_part(X - Y,Vars) :-
    variable_part(X,V1),
    variable_part(Y,V2),
    append(V1,V2,Vars).
```

and use it on a query like this:

```
?- variable_part((23+v(x))-(v(y)-v(x)), Vs).
Vs = [(x, 1),  (y, 1),  (x, 1)] ;
false.
```

Then you only need to go through the list and add the coefficients without needing to worry about accidentally unifying Prolog variables.